# STM32 DMA BUFFER USAGE

Tags: dma

I am using DMA for ADC and UART on my project and ADC has higher priority than USART. The ADC handles joystick and the UART handles keyboard. The ADC has 2 byte buffer and the USART has one byte buffer.

While all data was streaming , I traced the USART buffer and I saw that when I moved joystick it affects UART buffer content. On the other hand, the UART buffer was not giving those values as an output in interrupt callback; It was working well. That means it was giving the correct value that came from keyboard.

When I traced buffer directly, the UART buffer changes whenever I move the joystick, yet the interrupt was returning the correct keyboard data.

Okay, I know only one DMA channel works at a time and priority defines this but I am still confused how this is happening. There must be something about DMA buffer which I can not explain.

Comment: "*it affects UART buffer's value but, on the other hand UART buffer was not giving those values,*" Huh?

Comment: @DKNguyen sorry English is not my main. I tried to fix.

Comment: Makes more sense now.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes, thank you.

Comment: Which STM32 model it is? Some STM32 models have a FIFO for USART. What data rates are needed for these? To me, using DMA for sampling joystick and keyboard sounds awfully overkill. What is the transfer size used for DMA blocks?

Comment: @Justme I created these buffer sizes for DMA. STM32F407, what you try to mean when sayin data rate ? I set timer triggerred ADC and this was 5ms. What is it mean that awfully overkill ? I dont see any overkill behaviour. All outputs are stabile except instant content of keyboard dma buffrr.

Comment: I am just trying to say that using DMA to receive 1-byte blocks from UART takes more overhead per byte than simply using interrupts to receive each byte. So ADC is sampled 200 times per second. What is the baud rate for UART and what kind of keyboard data goes there and how often? What kind of keyboard it is?

Comment: Oh sorry, now baudrate 115200,uart data depends on me now. If i want to send char, im pressing keyboard so this means so few frequeny. From pc btw pc keyboard. @Justme